# t-distributed/robust likelihood

Tags: neural-networks, likelihood

In [this paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/file/07211688a0869d995947a8fb11b215d6-Paper.pdf), the authors claim to be using a robust likelihood function:

[image: Excerpt from paper]

The code for this paper is on [github](https://github.com/SkafteNicki/john/blob/3615cff6e98de343ddbb62d1c9ed3060f6b56a21/utils.py#L200) and is referred to as `t_likelihood`. Isn't this just a log Gaussian likelihood? What's robust about this function?

If you want to trace through the code:

1. The model described in this paper is [here](https://github.com/SkafteNicki/john/blob/master/experiment_regression.py#L484)
2. The paper describes modelling the mean and variance of a distribution using two neural networks and is trained at approximately [here](https://github.com/SkafteNicki/john/blob/master/experiment_regression.py#L484)

Comment: I'm not claiming to understand the paper in its entirety, but IIUC, the authors use the term "robust" when describing how they use a Bayesian hierarchical model with an inverse gamma prior. They use the HT algorithm to "unbias" the mini-batch estimator which they claim has better convergence properties than a full estimate being sparser due to less data in the sample.

Comment: I've re-read the paper and also the online supplementary material and I think this is the closest answer. By "robust" they sample variance from an inverse Gamma distribution (in the paper, even though the code seems to be using a regular gamma distribution).

Comment: So I'll turn it into an answer 8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not claiming to understand the paper in its entirety, but if I understand it correctly, the authors use the term "robust" when describing how they use a Bayesian hierarchical model with an inverse gamma prior on the sigma parameter of the Gaussian distribution. The resulting predictive distribution is a Student-t which is the common substitute for the normal when the variance is unknown.

The authors use the HT algorithm to "unbias" the mini-batch estimator which they claim has better convergence properties than a full estimate being sparser due to having less data to crunch in each of the individual samples.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is that for many non-normal probability models the likelihood has the appearance of a normal likelihood with increasing sample size.

The justification in this setting may be similar to using a chi-square approximation for the sampling distribution of the likelihood ratio test statistic, or using a normal approximation for the sampling distribution of the Wald test statistic when the data generative process is non-normal.  [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552014/intuition-for-wilks-theorem/552046#552046) is a related thread on Wilk's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Seems like they call it "robust" because they sample variance from an inverse Gamma distribution.