# Intuition behind the null distribution of the deviance statistic in survival models

Tags: survival, residuals, diagnostic, deviance

I am reading Tutz & Schmid ["Modeling Discrete Time-to-Event Data"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28158-2) (2016) chapter 4 Evaluation and Model Choice section 4.2 Residuals and Goodness-of-Fit. A goodness-of-fit statistic called deviance is defined as
$$
D = 2 \sum_{i=1}^N n_i \sum_{t=1}^k p_{it} \log\left( \frac{p_{it}}{\hat\pi_{it}} \right)
$$
where $\hat\pi_{it}$ is the estimated probability for a person belonging to group $i$ (of size $n_i$, among $N$ groups in total) to experience an event in the time period $t$ (from 1 to $k$), and $p_{it}$ is the corresponding observed proportion of persons in group $i$ that indeed experienced the event in the time period $t$.

A well-fitting model will produce values $\hat\pi_{it}$ that are close the the observed proportions $p_{it}$, though there will be discrepancies due to sampling variability inherent in $p_{it}$. This will yield $\frac{p_{it}}{\hat\pi_{it}}\approx 1$ and thus $\log\left( \frac{p_{it}}{\hat\pi_{it}} \right)\approx 0$ and thus $D\approx 0$. (Correct me if I am wrong.)

On the other hand, there is a later statement on the same page that asymptotically $D\sim\chi^2(N(k-1)-p)$. Now, I know $\chi^2(N(k-1)-p)$ can be obtained as a sum of squares of $N(k-1)-p$ independent N(0,1) random variables or as a sum of squares of a different number of dependent ones. However, I do not get the intuition why $p_{it} \log\left( \frac{p_{it}}{\hat\pi_{it}} \right)$ should behave like a square of N(0,1). Perhaps it should not? More generally, how is the asymptotic $\chi^2(N(k-1)-p)$ distribution obtained? (Intuition is welcome.)

Moreover, it seems to me that $\log\left( \frac{p_{it}}{\hat\pi_{it}} \right)$ and thus $p_{it} \log\left( \frac{p_{it}}{\hat\pi_{it}} \right)$ can be both lesser and greater than zero, and so $D$ could end up being negative. That is incompatible with a $\chi^2(N(k-1)-p)$ distribution. Am I getting this wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section of the Tutz and Schmid book assumes that there is no censoring, so this result is just the application of maximum-likelihood analysis to a multinomial distribution of events over the $k$ time periods.

Following Section 1.5.1 of the second edition of Agresti's [Categorical Data Analysis](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0471249688), the multinomial log-likelihood function for a model with a set of probabilities $\pi$ given $n_j$ observations in $j$ categories (total $N$ observations) is:

$$ L(\pi)=\sum_j n_j \log(\pi_j)$$

where $\pi_j$ is the modeled probability of category $j$.

The displayed deviance formula follows the standard definition (e.g., Section 4.5 of Agresti): twice the difference in log-likelihood between a saturated model with the maximum likelihood:

$$\sum_j n_j \log(n_j/N)= \sum_j n_j \log(p_j),$$
where $p_j$ is the observed probability of category $j$, and that of the model in question:

$$\sum_j n_j \log(\pi_j).$$

As the data have maximum likelihood under the saturated model, the likelihood under any other model cannot exceed that. So the *sum of terms* contributing to the displayed deviance formula is necessarily non-negative, even if individual terms might be negative.

The *asymptotic* chi-square distribution comes from [Wilks's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27_theorem). Agresti provides a proof specific to the multinomial likelihood-ratio statistic in Section 14.3.4. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/552014/28500) and its links provide some intuition about Wilks's theorem. For degrees of freedom, I suppose you can think about this as $(k-1)$ independent time periods (no censoring, so the results for $k-1$ periods determine that for the $k^{th}$ period) for $N$ groups, less the $p$ fitted parameters.

In terms of using the deviance *residuals* in survival analysis (in models that incorporate censored data), [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) note in Section 4.3:

> The deviance residual was designed to improve on the martingale residual for revealing individual outliers, particularly in plotting applications. In practice it has not been as useful as anticipated.

I can't say that I've found them very useful, unlike the scaled Schoenfeld residuals for evaluating proportional hazards assumptions, or martingale residuals for evaluating functional forms.