# Why not always use CI's from LRT since they don't require symmetry?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I'm confused on why anyone would appeal to asymptotic normality of mle,

$$\hat{\theta} - \theta_0 \rightarrow^D N(0,I^{-1}(\theta))$$

When we can simply invert the likelihood ratio test

$$L(\hat{\theta}) - L(\theta_0) \rightarrow^D \chi^2_1$$

to obtain a $(1-\alpha)$ CI. Is there a situation where this is not a good idea?

Comment: There are other options too, such as inverting a score test.

Comment: Agreed, but why not always use something (LRT, score etc) that converge to chi square to exploit asymmetric CIs?

Comment: The $\chi^2$ distribution of the likelihood-ratio test is [an asymptotic result, too](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/503710), so I don't see what conceptual difference your approach would make.

Answer (score 3):

The asymptotic distribution

$$\hat{\theta} - \theta_a \rightarrow^D N(0,I^{-1}(\theta))$$

can be rewritten as

$$\hat{\theta}  \rightarrow^D N(\theta_a,I^{-1}(\theta))$$

and it becomes easy to compute p-values for different hypothetical values $\theta_a$ and associated confidence intervals.

This expression $\hat{\theta} - \theta_a$ is a simple translation. This is not the case for $L(\hat{\theta}) - L(\theta_a)$.

---

A complication is $I^{-1}(\theta)$ which is probably gonna need to be $I^{-1}(\theta_a)$ and changing the value of $\theta_a$ might be not the same as a simple translation (but also change the variance). An example is the [Wilson score interval for a binomial proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval).